# Postgresql syntax for past 6 week sales and previous 6 weeks sales

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql(9.3) database and Pentaho report designer for reports designing. My requirement is, I need to create two drop down parameter( year & week) in pentaho, where year parameter displays years and week parameter displays week numbers as 1,2,3...52. Till here I have no issues but I got stuck in SQL query. Actually, when I select anyone of the week number in the week parameter for eg, 20, i need to populate data from 15-20 weeks and also the previous 6 weeks 10-15. Even more, if I select week number 2, it has to fetch the record of the previous years for eg: 48(2013) to 2(2014) and 6 weeks even before that. Can some one help me out to resolve this..

Thanks,
Abdur Rahmaan

Comment: Please post your table structures and preferably some sample data with desired outpt